# Benchmark instances for directed 3-Cycle cover

Tags: optimization, graph-theory, combinatorics, data-sets

The directed 3-Cycle cover asks for a vertex-covering set of oriented cycles with at least three vertices per cycle such that every vertex is covered by exactly one cycle.

I have scrutinzed the internet for some time for freely availabe benchmark problems but couldn't find anything useful.

So my question is where I can find such instances with known optimal solutions that were hard to find, resp., how such instances can be created.

The reason for asking is that I found a new algorithm for the problem and want to get a feeling about its quality and robustness.

Comment: Can't you just take any undirected graph and test if there is a 3-cycle cover? If my memory is not betraying me (it has been many years since I took graph theory), that can be done in polynomial time. Once you gather some graphs, you can test your algorithm (together with other algorithms) for robustness. https://sparse.tamu.edu/ has many sparse matrices that you can make into (un)directed graphs.

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas sorry for replying so late. You remembered the fact that the existence of 3-cycle covers can be checked in polynomial time for *undirected* graphs via the reduction to matching by Tutte. For a directed graph the problem is in NP as soon as you restrict the lengths of the cycles from above or below and ruling out cycles of length two is such a restriction.